# OCI_INVALID_HANDLE - Invalid service context, connection or statement handle

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I make some calls from C through OCI to an Oracle database.

I get this error:

> OCI_INVALID_HANDLE - Invalid service context, connection or statement handle

I inherited this code:

```
initOracle(..) { .. //return successful or 0 }

int executeGetQuery(char * query, char * queryResultData) {
    char stmt[255];

    OCIError *errhp;
    OCIDefine *defnp = (OCIDefine *) 0;
    OCIStmt *stmthp;
    OCISvcCtx *svchp; //server context handle (almost like DBPROCESS)
    sb2 is_null;

    memset((char *)stmt, 0, 255);
    //TODO replace with query
    sprintf((char *)stmt, "SELECT min(ID) as MINID FROM BNS_SAA_CONFIRMATIONS where SentToWssStatus<>'T'");

    /* prepare statement */
    if( checkerr(errhp, OCIStmtPrepare(stmthp, errhp, (text *) stmt,
            (ub4) strlen((char *) stmt),
            (ub4) OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT)) == OCI_ERROR)
        return -1;

    /* define output params */
    if(checkerr(errhp, OCIDefineByPos(stmthp, &defnp, errhp, 1, (dvoid *) queryResultData,
            (sword) strlen(queryResultData), SQLT_STR, (dvoid *) &is_null, (ub2 *)0,
            (ub2 *)0, OCI_DEFAULT)) == OCI_ERROR)//maybe replace SQLT_STR w SQLT_CHR OMFWTD
        return -1;

    /* execute the statement */
    status = OCIStmtExecute(svchp, stmthp, errhp, (ub4) 1, (ub4) 0, (CONST OCISnapshot *) NULL, (OCISnapshot *) NULL, OCI_DEFAULT);
    .... 
}
```

I think the error surfaces on these functions: `OCIStmtExecute(..)` or `OCIDefineByPos(..)` or `OCIStmtPrepare(..)`

**Question:**
How do I get rid of this error and start executing the query?

Error documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci02bas.htm

Comment: You've got a long way to go... you seem to have a bunch of handles that are local to the function, but they don't seem to be allocated anywhere. To start with I see no code to connect to the server at all here, that's what you need to do to have a meaningful `OCISvcCtx.` I would advise you to read to the intro to OCI programming documentation and take advantage of all the demo code oracle provides, found in Appendix B of the docs you link to.

Comment: I want to accept your comment as an answer :) It was those local variables which have meaningless names (to me). Please post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I see that OCI handles which are defined locally are not being either allocated and/or initialized correctly. If those steps are being done in some other code you inherited, you will need to ensure that you have a way to get the pointers to those handles. If not, the Oracle docs which you link to the error handling section of have both a great intro to OCI programming, and in-depth demo programs (you may have to create an Oracle developer account and download the OCI client to get them if they're not somewhere accessible to you). Good luck, the OCI is a huge API, but Oracle's own documentation is great once you learn how to navigate through it, other than the intro I found the [OCI Relational functions section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci16rel.htm#i560652) (at least it's equivalent in 10g) to be invaluable.

Comment: I instantiate them somewhere else, and I didn't know how these vars were used. The solution was to extern the vars so I can use the instantiated ones. Thanks!